# How do I get tool tips to work on 2 data set half doughnut chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a half doughnut chart using 2 datasets similar to a credit score indicator.  The inner chart displays the range and the outer shows the users current score opposed to the range.  I can't seem to get the labels worked out for both datasets.  I need the tool tips on the range to display the range which I have no issues doing but the same values appear for the outer chart as well.  I want the outer chart tips to display the current user score.

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [
                'Very Bad',
                'Poor',
                'Fair',
                'Good',
                'Very Good',
                'Excellent'
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Current Score",
                    data: [650, 850],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(20, 127, 171, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    label: "Score Range",
                    data: [300, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(188, 32, 38, 1)',
                        'rgba(235, 71, 35, 1)',
                        'rgba(246, 142, 31, 1)',
                        'rgba(254, 204, 9, 1)',
                        'rgba(125, 187, 66, 1)',
                        'rgba(15, 146, 70, 1)'
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
            circumference: 1 * Math.PI
        }``
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50043412/how-to-add-a-second-set-of-labels-to-a-chart-js-doughnut-chart) from Aniko Litvanyi on the same type of labeling issue. Chart JS has options for a tooltip callback function to read two sets of labels. I have included this incorporated in your chart below.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {

    datasets: [{
        label: "Current Score",
        data: [650, 850],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(20, 127, 171, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)'
        ],
        labels: [
          'Label 1',
          'Label 2'
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "Score Range",
        data: [300, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(188, 32, 38, 1)',
          'rgba(235, 71, 35, 1)',
          'rgba(246, 142, 31, 1)',
          'rgba(254, 204, 9, 1)',
          'rgba(125, 187, 66, 1)',
          'rgba(15, 146, 70, 1)'
        ],
        labels: [
          'Very Bad',
          'Poor',
          'Fair',
          'Good',
          'Very Good',
          'Excellent'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          var index = tooltipItem.index;
          return dataset.labels[index] + ': ' + dataset.data[index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```